# How to create a JWT token using angular 2 typescript

Tags: angular, angular2-jwt

```
IN Component

import * as jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';

var maykey = privatekey;
var token = jwt.sign({ foo: 'bar' }, maykey, { algorithm: 'RS256' });
```

I am getting below error.

Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: crypto.createSign is not a function
TypeError: crypto.createSign is not a function

Comment: What's the point of generating a JWT at client-side? If you do it at client side, your private key is public. So anywone can counterfeit your token.

Comment: Please migrate this to server side. Most probably inside authentication method (if any) .

Answer (score -1):

As already suggested you should always generate the token at server side to prevent security risk.

The way you are generating is only valid for node.js .See details here

1. https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken/issues/317
2. https://github.com/kjur/jsrsasign/wiki/Tutorial-for-JWT-generation